# Findall regex in python

Tags: python, regex, iterable, findall

When i run the scirpt below, i get no output at all. What i really want to do is: Create a string from an iterable and then use this string as an argument to `re.findall`.
`Print(tab)`, gives `a-z0-9`.

```
import re   

 my_tab = ['a-z',
            '0-9']

    tab = ''.join(my_tab)
    line = 'and- then 3 times minus 456: no m0re!'

    re.findall('tab', 'line')
```

What am i missing here? Is this the most pythonic way to achieve this??

Comment: Is that your actual code, or is your code: `re.findall(tab, line)` - ie, using names instead of literals?

Comment: Python is not perl or php, here 'tab' is just a string and will not include the value of variable `tab`.
But in perl this is valid : `$tab = 'tab'; print '$tab'` prints `'tab'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done `'tab'` and not `tab`. One is a string, another is a variable. You want to do `re.findall(tab, line)` (see how tab is no longer a string). You also did this for `line`.

However, if you print `tab` beforehand, you'll notice you have:

```
a-z0-9
```

When I think you're intending to have

```
[a-z0-9]
```

So you can concatenate strings:

```
>>> print re.findall('['+tab+']',line) # Here we add a bracket to each side
                                       # of a-z0-9 to create a valid regex 
                                       # capture group [a-z0-9]
['a', 'n', 'd', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '3', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e', 's', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'u', 's', '4', '5', '6', 'n', 'o', 'm', '0', 'r', 'e']
```

Or you can use `str.format()`:

```
>>> print re.findall('[{}]'.format(tab),line)
['a', 'n', 'd', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '3', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e', 's', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'u', 's', '4', '5', '6', 'n', 'o', 'm', '0', 'r', 'e']
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks a lot!. If i am not asking to much can u edit your answer and comment the `print re.findall('['+tab+']',line)`. I do not fully comprehend it..

Comment: @LDN-5602 I added a comment to explain it. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

This will not work, you are telling the regular expression to search for the string `'tab'` in the string `'line'` .

Even if you did not make that mistake. And did indeed search using the string `'a-z 0-9'` which you *named* `tab` with the string `'and- then 3 times minus 456: no m0re!'` which you named `line` you would find nothing, this is because `'a-z 0-9'` is not valid as regular expression capture group, and will result in no matches in this case.

If you wanted to find any instance of a lower-case letter (a-z) or a number (0-9) you could use this:

```
>>> re.findall('([a-z\d])', 'and- then 3 times minus 456: no m0re!')
['a', 'n', 'd', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '3', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e', 's', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'u', 's', '4', '5', '6', 'n', 'o', 'm', '0', 'r', 'e']
```

But I do not see how this helps you? Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do.. Either way, I suggest you read about [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to learn more.

Comment: I am actually and this part of my reading. Well this chunk is part of a script, which will read and write from/to text files. So what i am trying is to allow only some characters listed on `my_tab` to be written as output.

Comment: If this helped you, you could [Accept my Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192545), if you still need more help, make it clear, but you should probably ask a new question. Or come to the [Python Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: Yes it helped a lot, and it certainly answered my question. Still i insist in using a table. See the comment below and you will understand i think.. As far for the other part of it i am preparing a more specific question.

Comment: I never said you shouldn't use a table, just showing a more correct regex. You could construct the regex however you want :)

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(tab, line)
```

You have used two strings not variables. And actually I think what you want is `re.findall('[a-z0-9]', line)`. But for this goal, you could just use list comprehension `[x for x in list(line) if x != ' ']`.

Comment: `re.findall('[a-z0-9]` it is indeed but if u add some more characters it will become unreadable, therefore i am using a table.